# Prevent user access PHP page directly

Tags: php, html, security

I have a production public e-commerce website that are dealing with real currency. I want only logged in user (authorized) to view and use the function.

1. Are there any potential vulnerability where any person directly call **www.mywebsite.com/get_content.php?abc** thus calling the function within?
2. Also, is my current coding method sufficient? Please provide the best guidelines to follow for production e-commerce website.

I am really new to PHP and would like to implement security in it.

**Product.php** <-accessible through navbar

```
<?php
    include 'start_session.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <?php
        include 'get_content.php';
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**start_session.php** <-A PHP within **Product.php**. Duplicate across other page

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

**get_content.php** <-A PHP page only for **Product.php** for easy readability and maintain

```
<?php
function abc(){
    //do something
}

if((isset($_SESSION['user_id']))){
    //connect db and get content
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best practices, try using a framework like Laravel or Yii2. Then implement the authentication system as needed.

For creating your own authentication system, you will want to have a session with a user_id for logged in users, then create a check at the top of each logged in user page that checks for the session user id, and if not set will redirect to the log in page.

A cleaner way to handle if the user is not logged in, is to do one simple check at the top.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['users_id'])){
//redirect to login page and exit script
header('Location: /login.php');
exit;
}
```

Comment: In my case, I need to add if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){}else{//redirect to index.php} in every page including Product.php and get_content.php?? Both?

Comment: I put all my functions in 2 different pages. One page for functions that are public and two for ones that are for users logged in. Then I just add the session check for user logged in the second one. I just have to keep track of placing the correct function in the right page.

Comment: Just check if they are not logged in, then redirect to login page using header('Location: /login.php'); exit;

Answer (score 1):

First you are going to want to call the `start_session();` within the get_content.php file

```
<?php
start_session();
function abc(){
    //do something
}

if((isset($_SESSION['user_id']))){
    //connect db and get content
}
?>
```

Then in your login script when the user logs in add some variables to session that tell your scripts the user is logged into the site. This is a basic none secure method but gives you the idea

```
$_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = true;
```

Then change your `get_content.php` file to something like this

```
<?php
start_session();
if ($_SESSION['user_logged_in'] == true) {
    function abc(){
        //do something
    }

    if((isset($_SESSION['user_id']))){
        //connect db and get content
    }
} else {
    //redirect user to the login screen
}
?>
```

If the user is not logged in, they can't access the scripts

Comment: I think that your $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] is similar to my $_SESSION['user_id'] except that I store user ID (id from database) in it and you just check boolean. Am I right?

Comment: yup I just showed a very basic method. I store `$_SESSION['user_id']` as well typically and later call the DB to check if they match.

Comment: if(!isset($_SESSION['users_id'])){
    //redirect to login page and exit script
    }            Try to avoid huge scopes if not needed.

Comment: @CesarBielich Both answer are great and I have to choose 1. Thank you.